# In VS2010, what environment setting applies to mouse-over on region/sub collapse/expand?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, themes, development-environment, environment

I'm tweaking my environment settings and I've got all my colors happy except this one.
When you hover over the "+" or "-" the entire affected area gets highlighted in white-ish color. This is annoying when you have a dark background like I have using Ragnarok Blue (or ZenBurn)

What Display Item is this so I can adjust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By going through each display item I discovered it's the "Collapsible Region" 
I suppose that should have been obvious.